# Angular 2 Services object undefined from service Call

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I've some service, which loads some static Data from my backend and I am Injecting this service in component and then I am binding some data to the component template.

My Problem is, that I have to check every call if my "iniModel" is defined, when I don't do this I later get a error that its not defined.

```
@Injectable()
export class PageInformationsService {
  private initModel : Account.Models.IPageInformationsInitModel;

constructor(private accountService: Accountservice) {
    this.init();
}

private init() : void {
    this.accountService.getPageInformationsInitModel().subscribe(result => {
        this.initModel = result;
    });
}

public get currentUserName(): string {
    if (this.initModel) {
        return this.initModel.CurrentUserName;
    }
    return "";
}
```

I am injecting this Static Data service into my component.

```
import {PageInformationsService} from "../../AppGlobal/Services/pageInformations.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'sxp-app-header',
  template: `<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{pageInformationService?.myDeskLink}}" target="_self">
                <img src="/Images/Logo.png" />
            </a>`
})
export class AppHeaderComponent {
  constructor(public pageInformationService: PageInformationsService) { }
}
```

I need to check every call with "if(this.initModel)" is there a better solution or I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: What is `myDeskLink`?

Comment: you may initialize `this.initModel` to an empty object, what is happening is currentUserName property is getting evaluated before your `getPageInformationsInitModel` service returns the result, Hope this helps!!

Comment: @echonax just a string property